# Floating relative divs with absolute children

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add caption of images on top of the image. These images should be floating in a grid-like system (without an fixed height!) like in the fiddle I made over here http://jsfiddle.net/thomasjonas/GzjuM/3/

You can already see te problem... Because of the absolute positioning of the title and image inside the relative item div, the relative item div doesn't get the appropriate height, but just the height of the border... How can I fix this? I have looked for answers everywhere, but most of the time the problems of others are solved using a different approach. The only other approach I know for my problem is using an image as a background for a div, but then I need to know the width and height of my image... What is the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't position the images absolute. Instead render the `<div class="image">` elements as block (using `display:block` if you changed your `div` style somewhere) and set up a margin instead of fiddling with absolute positioning:

```
.item .image{
    display:block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-left: 1em;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GzjuM/4/)

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot about the display property.